# Invalid method declaration; return type required WebView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I learn android and I want to make WebView in Fragment. I wrote this

```
package app.com.youtubeapiv3.fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;


import app.com.youtubeapiv3.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class WebView extends Fragment {

    public WebView() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);
        WebView mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        return v;
    }

}
```

I get message error like

> error: invalid method declaration; return type required error:
>    expected

Method loeadUrl() and getSettings(); cannot be resolved. I don't know what I should do.

[image]

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.WebView">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problems seems to be in your `findviewbyid` method. Check the id of the webview in your `fragment_web_view` is it `webview`? If this doesn't solve the problem post your `fragment_web_view` xml

Comment: It doesn't work. I added my fragment_web_view.xml

Comment: The problem is the `WebView` conflicts with the Fragment(Because both of them have the same name `WebView`), my suggestion is to rename the Fragment to something else like `MyCustomWebView`